# How to turn a list of lists of 2 into a single list of 2?

Tags: r

So I have a list of curves, each curve is represented with a list of x and y coordinates. I want to essentially make a single long curve by combining the x coordinates of all the curves and the y coordinates of all the curves into a single list of x and y coordinates.

Here is an example, suppose I have

```
toy <- list(list(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6)), list(c(0,0), c(1,1)), list(c(1,2), c(1,2)))
toy
```

---

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 4 5 6


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 0 0

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 1 1


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[3]][[2]]
[1] 1 2
```

How do I get `toy` to look like

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 0 0 1 2

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 4 5 6 1 1 1 2
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option with `transpose`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
transpose(toy)  %>%
       map(flatten_dbl) %>%
       list
#[[1]]
#[[1]][[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3 0 0 1 2

#[[1]][[2]]
#[1] 4 5 6 1 1 1 2
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
list(lapply(asplit(t(simplify2array(toy)), 2), unlist))
```